# Perc H710 on Windows 2016

Tags: windows, raid, database, dell-perc

Excuse me for a naive question. I just got R720 with 4x3T on RAID 5 using H710. In the server manager, I saw disk with 8T which I suppose is the virtual disk I set up using H710; In volumes, there is a C: with 2T capacity. I can find the 2T storage on local disk (C:) but how can i access the 8T disk storage? My goal is to setup a database server. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A disk (or a RAID array) isn't assigned any drive letters before it's initialized and partitioned. You should first [initialize the disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/initialize-new-disks) using the Disk Management or [`Initialize-Disk`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/initialize-disk) PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you! And I need to switch to UEFI and convert disk into GPT to use disk larger than 2T.